# The more the features the more perfect the linear model

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

I need to know more about the relationship between the number of features and linear model regression, based on this paragraph on the page 47 of the book "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python", by Andreas C. Müller & Sarah Guido:

"For datasets with many features, linear models can be very powerful.
In particular, if you have more features than training data points, any target y
can be perfectly modeled (on the training set) as a linear function"

How is it explained by the linear algebra?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can try and give you an intuitive answer.

Imagine you have a training dataset composed by a single data point in 2 dimensions. In this case, we have `n_data = 1` (the number of data points), and `n_features = 2` (`n_features` > `n_data`). The training dataset can be perfectly modelled by a 1D linear function `y = a0`.

Similarly, if you have three features (i.e. three dimensions) and two data points (so `n_features = 3` > `n_data = 2`), those two points can always be modelled by a 2D line of the form `y = a0 + a1 x1`.

In four dimensions (four features), three points can always be modelled by a (hyper)plane defined by a linear equation of the form `y = a0 + a1x1 + a2x2`.

In general, a hyperplane (defined as any plane with a fewer number of dimensions than those of its ambient space) can always be defined with a linear formula `a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 + ... + an*xn = b`. Therefore, if the number of points is less than those of the dimensions, a hyperplane can always be found, and therefore it will always be possible to model a set of training data if the number of samples is less than the number of features (which correspond to the dimensions of the space).

Comment: Thanks, but I have come up with a new question. If we had two observation (2 points) and three features (3D), we could model our data either by a line or by many planes. How to deal with this situation?

Comment: @MiladRahbar indeed, your comment can be expanded to all dimensions! 1 observation in 2D can be modelled by an infinite amount of lines – the statement still holds true, my case was the simplest one, in which the coefficient for the highest n-dimension is equal to zero. Whether, in a 3D case, the model will be a line or a plane, will depend on various factors, amongst which the initial parameters (if they are all zero all the parameters that can be zero will likely stay zero!), the learning algorithm, etc.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and patience answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more suitable for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) community.

The keyword here is **"on the training set"**!

> "For datasets with many features, linear models can be very powerful.
>   In particular, if you have more features than training data points,
>   any target *y* can be perfectly modeled (**on the training set**) as a
>   linear function",
>   *Introduction to Machine Learning with Python, by Andreas C. Müller & Sarah Guido*.

In general **more features than data points (or more variables/predictors than samples/observations) lead to [model overfitting](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/machine-learning/the-problem-of-overfitting-ACpTQ)**. If we have too many features, the learned hypothesis may fit the training set very well, but fail to generalize to new examples (on the test set). Consider for example a dataset consisting of 1000 images, each of which has 300x300 pixels (1000 samples and 90000 features).

The problem with more predictors than observations (usually indicated as **p>n**) is that there is then no unique solution to a standard [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) problem. **This is how it is explained by linear algebra.** If rows of the matrix of data points represent cases and columns represent predictors, there are necessarily linear dependences among the columns of the matrix. So once you've found coefficients for **n** of the predictors, the coefficients for the other **p-n** predictors can be expressed as arbitrary linear combinations of those first **n** predictors. Other approaches like `LASSO` or `ridge regression`, or a variety of other machine-learning approaches, provide ways to proceed in such cases.

There is a good [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223486/modelling-with-more-variables-than-data-points) on the Cross Validated:

> It's certainly possible to fit good models when there are more
>   variables than data points, but this must be done with care.
>
> When there are more variables than data points, the problem may not
>   have a unique solution unless it's further constrained. That is, there
>   may be multiple (perhaps infinitely many) solutions that fit the data
>   equally well. Such a problem is called `ill-posed` or
>   `underdetermined`. **For example, when there are more variables than
>   data points, standard least squares regression has infinitely many
>   solutions that achieve zero error on the training data**.
>
> Such a model would certainly overfit because it's "too flexible" for
>   the amount of training data. As model flexibility increases (e.g. more
>   variables in a regression model) and the amount of training data
>   shrinks, it becomes increasingly likely that the model will be able to
>   achieve a low error by fitting random fluctuations in the training
>   data that don't represent the true, underlying distribution.
>   Performance will therefore be poor when the model is run on future
>   data drawn from the same distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Before, discussing relationship between the number of features and linear model regression, let me clear about difference between attribute or predictor and feature.

Attribute or predictor is the first level input variable, while feature may be of first level or second level. Here, first level means predictor as an input variable for predicing response or output. The second level means feature as a nonlinear transformation of the predictor or input variable using some basis or feature map to capture inherited special structure.

Now, coming to your question from linear algebra perspective. If the number of features say it dimension $p>>n$ then the number of samples n is too small to allow for accurate estimation of the parameters. In the case of $p>>n$ the associated linaer system $y=\textbf{X}\omega $ of the linear model is under-determined and having infinitely many solutions, so we can find the best solution using least norm solution.

Another approach is that, we assume that the model is sparse and But if the true model is sparse with sparsity measure $s<n$ (the number of non-zero parameters in the underlying model), then it turns out that we can estimate the parameters effectively, using the lasso and related methods.