# n_features > n_data then perfect linear model claim from intro to machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

This question has been answered [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684309/the-more-the-features-the-more-perfect-the-linear-model?newreg=c8e5815c13f84596b9b68ed7beceadbe)

but not to my satisfaction.

In the book "intro to machine learning" the author says that as long as you have more features than points in the dataset, you can perfectly model any target as a linear function. I'm having trouble understanding why you can't perfectly model a situation with the same number of featuures and data points.

If you have 2 datapoints, you simply need a line to cut through both. a line only requires to features. If you have 3 data points, a plane cuts through all three. a plane only requires 3 features (dimesnions). What am I missing?

I tried to find an example of 2 or 3 data points that could not be modeled by a function in 2 or 3 dimensions but could not find one.